# $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}F_{\varepsilon_k}(x_{\varepsilon_k})=\liminf\limits_{\varepsilon\to0}\inf\limits_{x\in K}F_{\varepsilon}(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $(F_{\varepsilon})_{\varepsilon>0}$ be a family of functions from a metrizable space $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $K$ a set. I want to prove there exists a sequence $x_{\varepsilon_k}$ such that $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}F_{\varepsilon_k}(x_{\varepsilon_k})=\liminf\limits_{\varepsilon\to0}\inf\limits_{x\in K}F_{\varepsilon}(x)$?

What I tried is defining $g(\epsilon):=\inf\limits_{x\in K}F_{\epsilon}(x)$ and saying that there exists a sequence $(\varepsilon_k)_{k\ge1}$ such that $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}g(\varepsilon_k)=\liminf\limits_{\epsilon\to0}g(\epsilon)$. However I am not sure how to continue.

Comment: Please don't use titles that are entirely MathJax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ denotes the right side then we can write $A=\lim_k (\inf_{x \in K} F_{\epsilon_k} (x))$ for some sequence $(\epsilon_k)$ decreasing to $0$. For each $k$ we can find $x_k \in K$ such that $F_{\epsilon_k} (x_k)-\frac 1 k <\inf_{x \in K} F_{\epsilon_k} (x)) \leq F_{\epsilon_k} (x_k)$. Now $F_{\epsilon_k} (x_k)$ tends to $A$.